# Keeping a counter

Tags: php

**Here is what I am trying to acheive: **
Basically I have a form where people can submit events to our database. In the CMS I have a page which displays a record of the number of events.

**Here is what I have: **
After the button is clicked, this script is called:

```
if($subject_type == 'Event') {

  $query = "SELECT town, update_id, event_validex ";
  $query .= "FROM dev_town ";
  $query .= "LEFT JOIN updates ON dev_town.town_id = updates.town ";
  $query .= " WHERE sitename  = '".SITENAME."'";
  $query .= " AND month = " .date('m')." AND year =" .date('Y');

  $querys = $this->tep_db_query($query);
  $rows = $this->tep_db_fetch_array($querys);

  extract($rows); //extract rows, so you don't need to use array 

  $eventid = $event_validex + 1;

  $sql_data_array = array('event_validex' => $eventid);


  $submit_to_database = $this->tep_db_perform('updates', $sql_data_array, 'update', "town='".$town."'");
```

This works fine, however I cant seem to solve the next bit

**This is the Problem**
As you can see, it checks the database for the current month and adds it, this is providing that the sitename and that month are there, not a site and another month.

How would I get it to add the row in IF the sitename and month are not there?

I have been manually adding the months in now so that it works, and I am sure you can agree that's a ball ache.

Cheers peeps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if you want to check if site A + Month 11 exists do a select query against it and store the number of rows returned in a variable. ( $exists = mysql_num_rows("your query here"); )

then do an if statement against the $exists variable and proceed as you wish

```
if($exists) {
  // update
} else {
 // add
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly how your method "checks the database for the current month and **adds it** "; I'll just assume that the tep_db_perform() method of your class handles this somehow.

(uhk! n00bed it; rest of the post was somehow chopped off?) Since you're already hitting the database with the select with the intent of using the data if a record is found, then you could use the resultset assigned to $rows as a means of checking if a record exists with SITENAME and Month.

See below:

```
if($subject_type == 'Event') {

  // build query to check the database for sitename, month and year.
  $query = "SELECT town, update_id, event_validex ";
  $query .= "FROM dev_town ";
  $query .= "LEFT JOIN updates ON dev_town.town_id = updates.town ";
  $query .= " WHERE sitename  = '".SITENAME."'";
  $query .= " AND month = " .date('m')." AND year =" .date('Y');

  // Execute Query(wrapper for $result = mysql_query I guess?)
  $querys = $this->tep_db_query($query);

  // Get a resultset from database. --> you could merge this into one method with $this->tep_db_query
  $rows = $this->tep_db_fetch_array($querys);

  if(count($rows) > 0) {
    extract($rows); //extract rows, so you don't need to use array --> I try to stay away from extract() as it makes for random variables being created. 
    $eventid = $event_validex + 1;
    $sql_data_array = array('event_validex' => $eventid);
    $submit_to_database = $this->tep_db_perform('updates', $sql_data_array, 'update', "town='".$town."'");
  } else {
    // insert new record into database
    // updated with code to execute insert SQL query. 
    $insert = "INSERT INTO updates ('town','month','year','event_validex') VALUES ('".$town."','". date('m')."','". date('Y')."','1')"; 
    $result = $this->tep_db_query($query);
  }
.... 

}
```

If I've misunderstood something, please let me know, happy to work through it with you.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO updates ('town','month','year','event_validex') VALUES ('".$town."','". date('m')."','". date('Y')."','1')"; 
    $eventid =  1;
        $sql_data_array = array('event_validex' => $eventid);
        $submit_to_database = $this->tep_db_perform('updates', $sql_data_array, 'update', "town='".$town."'");


  }
 }
```

this is what  I have for the else statement there, however it will add one to the value if its there but will not add a new entry if its isnt.. ?

Comment: It's because you're not executing the $insert query, but running the same logic you would have run if rows are found.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the SQL you provided above, try that.

Comment: what about it "does not work"? is there an error? does it add it incorrectly? I can't guess how your class methods work so you'll need to do some digging around on how to execute a query using the class you're working with. Good luck buddy.

Comment: Cheers rvdavid. What happens is, IF the row in the db is already there it will add one to the value, but it does not create a row if it isnt.

Comment: Hello again, I don't know what to tell you; can you provide what code sample you've got so far?